# A source for the counterexample of Kadec 1/4 theorem

Tags: reference-request

Taken from *Austin, Anthony P., and Lloyd N. Trefethen. "Trigonometric interpolation and quadrature in perturbed points." SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis 55.5 (2017): 2113-2122.*:

> Kadec's theorem is an answer to a question of sampling theory that originates with Paley and Wiener. The exponentials $\left\{\exp \left(i \lambda_k x\right)\right\},-\infty<k<\infty$, form an orthonormal basis for $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ if $\lambda_k=k$ for each $k$. Thus, the sampling theorist would say that one can recover a function $f \in L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ from its inner products with the functions $\left\{\exp \left(i \lambda_k x\right)\right\}$. Now suppose these wave numbers are perturbed so that $\left|\tilde{\lambda}_k-k\right| \leq \alpha$ for some fixed $\alpha$. Can one still recover the signal? Specifically, does the family $\left\{\exp \left(i \tilde{\lambda}_k x\right)\right\}$ form a Riesz basis for $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$, that is, a basis that is related to the original one by a bounded transformation with a bounded inverse? Paley and Wiener showed that this is always the case for $\alpha<1 / \pi^2$, and Levinson showed that it is not always the case for $\alpha \geq 1 / 4$. Kadec's theorem shows that Levinson's construction was sharp: for any $\alpha<1 / 4$, the family $\left.\exp \left(i \tilde{\lambda}_k x\right)\right\}$ forms a Riesz basis.

From this passage, it appears that the counterexample to Kadec's theorem comes from Levinson's book **Gap and Density Theorems**.

Another important reference, instead, states:

> The first result on the nonharmonic Fourier series is due to Paley and N. Wiener: if $\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and
> $$
> \sup _{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\left|\lambda_n-n\right| \leqslant \delta
> $$
> with $\delta<\pi^{-2}$ (that is, $\left\{e^{i \lambda_n t}\right\}$ is close to the standart orthogonal basis $\left.\left\{e^{i n t}\right\}\right)$, then $\left\{e^{i \lambda_n t}\right\}$ is a Riesz basis in $L^2(0,2 \pi)$. Later, M. Kadec [21] showed that the same is true for any $\delta<1 / 4$, whereas, by a result of A. Ingham, the system $\left\{e^{i \lambda_n t}\right\}$ may fail to be a basis if $\delta=1 / 4$.

The reference in this case is *Baranov, Anton. "Stability of the bases and frames reproducing kernels in model spaces." Annales de l'institut Fourier. Vol. 55. No. 7. 2005.*

Unfortunately, no work by Ingham is cited in this article, although I suspect it may be the following one: *Ingham, Albert Edward. "Some trigonometrical inequalities with applications to the theory of series." Mathematische Zeitschrift 41.1 (1936): 367-379.* Unfortunately I can't find any evidence in it that allows me to say that "the system $\left\{e^{i \lambda_n t}\right\}$ may fail to be a basis if $\delta=1 / 4$".

In the book **'An Introduction to Nonharmonic Fourier Series' by Young**, the counterexample is provided without citing the source, although it appears similar to the one given by Levinson.

Does anyone know to whom the counterexample to Kadec's 1/4 theorem is attributed? Levinson or Ingham? Or have both of them provided one? If yes, in which of Ingham's works was this counterexample introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is Levenson. Because:

In [Density Results for Frames of Exponentials](https://zbmath.org/1129.42417) from

Heil, Christopher (ed.), Harmonic analysis and applications. In Honor of John J. Benedetto. Basel: Birkhäuser (ISBN 0-8176-3778-8/hbk). Applied and Numerical Harmonic Analysis, xvii-xxv (2006). [ZBL1099.01502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1099.01502).

it has been referred to Levinson's 1936 paper.

*Levinson, Norman*, [**On non-harmonic Fourier series**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968628), Ann. Math. (2) 37, 919-936 (1936). [ZBL0015.20804](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0015.20804).